# Strange Error When including Objective C header in Command Line App

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, console-application, osx-mountain-lion

I am creating a simple command line app that uses Core Foundation, so from what I understand, that means I can use Objective-C.

The problem is, as soon as I include my Objective-C header, I get 19 build errors.  The only line of code I added was the "include objective-c-header.h", the rest of my application is just the boiler plate code that XCode generates.

If I comment out that line, everything builds fine.

The errors are all parse errors and are in:
- NSObjCRuntime.h
- NSZone.h
- NSObject.h

Is the compiler trying to build these as regular C headers?  Is it possible to define an Objective C class in a command-line application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want *Foundation*, not *Core Foundation*. *Core Foundation* is a C-only framework and does not contain the Objective-C runtime libraries.